# Implement encryption ValueConverter with DataProtectionProvider using custom attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to implement encryption using Entity Framework Core code first. I would like to use a custom attribute to define which fields need to be encrypted/decrypted. My problems arrive when attempting to inject the DataProtectionProvider into the converter and 'protect'/'unprotect' inside of the converter expressions. I would also like to define the protection provider purpose in the call to my converter inside of OnModelCreating.

How can I inject an instance of IDataProtectionProvider into my encryption valueconverter and set the purpose based on the entity name in OnModelCreating?

I used this [link](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233708-using-value-converter-for-custom-encryption-of-field-on-entity-framework-core-2-1) to for my implementation.

Here is the ValueConverter that I would like to use DI instead of directly instantiating the dependency

```cs
public class EncryptedConverter : ValueConverter<string, string>
    {
        private static IDataProtector dataProtectorProvider = 
            DataProtectionProvider.Create("appName").CreateProtector("purpose");
        public EncryptedConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = default)
        : base(EncryptExpr, DecryptExpr, mappingHints)
        {
        }

        static Expression<Func<string, string>> DecryptExpr = 
            x => new string(dataProtectorProvider.Unprotect(x));
        static Expression<Func<string, string>> EncryptExpr = 
            x => new string(dataProtectorProvider.Protect(x));
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm newer to .NET Core so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here :)

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [latest post](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233774-using-data-protection-in-entity-framework-core-with-value-converters) on the subject that follows on from the implementation you used

Basically you have to use a wrapping class, then in your extended converter class create a constructor that takes IDataProtectionProvider and call another constructor in your extended converter class that wraps it with your wrapping class.  This constructor can then access the wrapping class expressions to call the base ValueConverter constructor.

```cs
public class ProtectedConverter : ValueConverter<string, string>
{
    class Wrapper
    {
        readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

        public Wrapper(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        {
            _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(nameof(ProtectedConverter));
        }

        public Expression<Func<string, string>> To => x => x != null ? _dataProtector.Protect(x) : null;
        public Expression<Func<string, string>> From => x => x != null ? _dataProtector.Unprotect(x) : null;
    }

    public ProtectedConverter(IDataProtectionProvider provider, ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = default)
        : this(new Wrapper(provider), mappingHints)
    { }

    ProtectedConverter(Wrapper wrapper, ConverterMappingHints mappingHints)
        : base(wrapper.To, wrapper.From, mappingHints)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the code of my [`EntityFramework.Core.DataEncryption`](https://github.com/Eastrall/EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption) library, it provides a `[Encrypted]` attribute that encrypts only `string` fields using a built-in or custom encryption providers. Actually, only the `AesProvider` has been developed.

There is a little sample of you encryption works with my library:

First, declare an entity and tag a `string` property with the `[Encrypted]` attribute.

```cs
public class UserEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Encrypted]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Encrypted]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then, update you `DbContext` and create a new `IEncryptionProvider` object and pass it to the `UseEncryption()` extension method of the `ModelBuilder` as explained bellow:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    // Get key and IV from a Base64String or any other ways.
    // You can generate a key and IV using "AesProvider.GenerateKey()"
    private readonly byte[] _encryptionKey = ...; 
    private readonly byte[] _encryptionIV = ...;
    private readonly IEncryptionProvider _provider;

    public DbSet<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
        this._provider = new AesProvider(this._encryptionKey, this._encryptionIV);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseEncryption(this._provider);
    }
}
```

Now, when you insert data, you will see the following in your database:
[image: encryption]

---

All the work occurs in the `ModelBuilder` extension method, as described [here](https://github.com/Eastrall/EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption/blob/master/src/EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption/ModelBuilderExtensions.cs).
You first need to load every properties of your entities that has the `[Encrypted]` attribute and then set the specified converter using the `property.SetValueConverter(encryptionConverter);` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've always read that you should use a given IV only once per encryption operation. Having a constant one is a security threat.

Comment: @Binarynam Just read some articles about that and you are correct. Thank you for pointing this out! I will plan an update of the library.

Comment: i'll be checking on what you've done, i'm interested in that kind of packaged solution ! Good luck with it.